# how to get all branchs from repository?

Tags: config, git-branch, git-bash

I'm a new user with git, and I use gitBash.
When I execute `$git clone http:..../name.git`, the master branch of **name** is downloading. But when I execute `$git branch -a` I just see the master branch, no others.

But I have some others branchs... Why I can't see all branches ? How do that ?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch -a` only displays local branches you have already checked out.

You want to use `git branch -r` (where `-r` stands for `remote`). This should list all the remote branches available (I can't test this right now, but I'm fairly certain it works).

Comment: ok,i tryed some commandes : $git branch => show 'master'. $git branch -a => show'master'. And $git branch -r => show nothing.. Why? Does that mean there aren't others branchs ? Because I'm sure there are others branchs on the distant repository ..;

Comment: ah! If I try $git ls-remote --heads http://....name.git, I can see the branch I want. But how can I clone it?